# How to parameter the disatance between nodes SFDP GraphViz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to use `GraphViz` to draw network graphics (`SFDP`), but I can't find out how to set the disatance between the nodes,

For example:

```
Node source  Node target    Distance
------------------------------------
Node1        Node2          4
Node1        Node3          2
Node1        Node4          9
```

I tried to use `labeldistance`, `len`, `sep`, but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Here is my code :

```
digraph G {
graph [bgcolor=grey96];
node [color= firebrick4, style=filled, fillcolor=rosybrown fontcolor=white];
"Node1"->"Node2"[labeldistance=1,color= green , sep="2",len=10];
"Node1"->"Node3"[labeldistance=2,color= palevioletred4, sep=9,len=1];
"Node1"->"Node4"[labeldistance=4,color= palevioletred4, sep=3,len=2];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, sfdp does not support variable edge lengths. (sfdp is a multilevel solver, and when merging edges of different lengths, it's not clear, what should be the length of the combined edge?)  Actually, there has been some good work recently on scalable layout with variable edge lengths, but it hasn't been incorporated into Graphviz.

Comment: Graphviz neato does support edge lengths (e.g.  a -- b [len=2] ) since it solves a full distance model between all node pairs.

Comment: Thnkas @north at graphviz, this information is very helpfull to me